# Comparing numbers with a unique base

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm using the days of the week represented with numbers. `0 = Sunday, ..., 6 = Saturday`

In the real world, without going backwards in time, if it's Saturday but need it to be Monday I need to wait two days to the correct. But I'm having a hard time logically creating a formula for this in JavaScript.

```
have, need, add
6,    1,    2
1,    1,    0
3,    4,    1
5,    4,    6
0,    1,    1
```

I was trying things like `(have+need)%6`, `(need-get+6)%6`, `(parseInt(have, 7) + parseInt(need, 7)).slice(-1)`, but I haven't been successful in getting anything to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working with the provided data:

```
Math.abs(((have - need)  - 7 ) % 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following formula works for all the examples in your question.

```
((7 - have) + need) % 7
```

```js
function getDay(h, n) {
  return ((7 - h) + n) % 7;
}

console.log(getDay(6, 1));
console.log(getDay(1, 1));
console.log(getDay(3, 4));
console.log(getDay(5, 4));
console.log(getDay(0, 1));
```